# Why is CreateFileAsync() continuation not executed?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

In the below code, the continuation of `CreateFileAsync()` neither prints nor accesses `pdone`.  However, the zero-length file, Hello.txt, is created.

```
auto pdone = make_shared<bool>(false);

create_task(folderLocal->CreateFileAsync("Hello.txt", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting)).then([pdone](StorageFile ^file) {
    OutputDebugString(L"In CreateFileAsync continuation!\n");
    *pdone = true;
});

create_task([pdone]{
    OutputDebugString(L"In my task!\n");
});

create_async([pdone]{
    OutputDebugString(L"In my async!\n");
});

while (!*pdone) {}
OutputDebugString(L"Done!\n");
```

In the debugger:

```
In my task!
In my async!
```

I'm not very familiar with debugging WinRT threads yet, but I do not see any obvious exception or any reason the continuation to the async operation should not execute.  The target platform is the Hololens emulator.

Any thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with StorageFile APIs - there's super slow and very clumsy to use. Just use CreateFile2 instead.

Comment: While you're spinning, the thread is busy so there's no way for the continuation to run.  I'm not very familiar with C++/CX but I believe that if this code is inside an event handler, you need to return from it.  The continuation will run later.

Answer (score 1):

Harry's comment above is most likely the culprit - if you initiated this on a UI thread then by default the C++ tasks library (PPL) will try to schedule the completion on the same thread. This will never happen if you are spinning the thread waiting for the completion to happen (classic deadlock).

If you must do this (*although you really should try and avoid it*) you need to use a "continuation context" to tell PPL to run the continuation somewhere else.

Here's an example. First, basic XAML (just paste inside the `Grid` of a blank C++ XAML project):

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Hang the UI thread" Click="Hang"/>
    <Button Content="Do not do this" Click="DoNotDoThis"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code (just paste after the `MainPage` constructor):

```
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace concurrency;

void DoIt(task_continuation_context& context)
{
  auto folder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
  auto done = std::make_shared<bool>(false);
  create_task(folder->CreateFileAsync(L"x", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting))
  .then([done](StorageFile^ file) mutable
  {
    OutputDebugString(L"Done creating file\n");
    *done = true;
  }, context);

  OutputDebugString(L"Going to wait... DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION CODE!\n");
  while (!*done)
    ;

  OutputDebugString(L"Done waiting\n");
}

void MainPage::Hang(Platform::Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
  OutputDebugString(L"Starting Hang\n");
  // The default context == the UI thread (if called from UI)
  DoIt(task_continuation_context::use_default());
  OutputDebugString(L"Ending Hang\n");
}

void MainPage::DoNotDoThis(Platform::Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
  OutputDebugString(L"Starting DoNotDoThis\n");
  // An arbitrary context will pick another thread (not the UI)
  DoIt(task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary());
  OutputDebugString(L"Ending DoNotDoThis\n");
}
```

As noted, **you shouldn't do this**. If you need synchronous File I/O, and you're accessing files in your own package, use the Win32 API `CreateFile2`. If you need to access files outside of your package (eg, from a file picker or the photos library) you should use a fully-async programming approach.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using task_continuation_context::use_arbitarty() is the correct way of doing this, however I think microsoft suggests using it slightly differently unless i have misunderstood this link (scroll all the way to the bottom): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750082.aspx

```
create_task(folderLocal->CreateFileAsync("Hello.txt", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting)).then([pdone](StorageFile ^file) {
    OutputDebugString(L"In CreateFileAsync continuation!\n");
    *pdone = true;
}, task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary());
```